# What is destination IP for mongoDB Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, shared-hosting

I am trying to run MongoDB Atlas in shared hosting and having some trouble connecting. I contacted support and they asked for:

1. Destination IP: Where is the connection going to
2. Port: Which port is this communication occurring on
3. Reason: What is the reason for this request, such as Gateway API.

What IP am I supposed to send them? I researched for the port and found Atlas uses 27017 port as default for connections. But I do not know what IP to send them.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: You cannot "run" Atlas in shared hosting. You can *use* Atlas in shared hosting. The connections are outgoing from your host to Atlas, is your hosting company restricting outgoing traffic?

Comment: Yes, they had blocked port 27017. I reached to the support and they allowed it. Not it's working.